# iptables - Redirect web traffic to LAN Server

Tags: iptables, router

I have a webserver which is running on ip address 192.168.11.100

How can i use iptables to redirect all web traffic (http and https) to my webserver on LAN?

After that i want to add except list mac address to this rule. How can i do that?

I tried this command but nothing happened with LAN IP.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.100
```

Update: with command above it seems like get affect. But i don't know why the result is: the webpage is not available.

But when i access 192.168.11.100 the server return me a index page. So how should i do?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the port number of 192.168.11.100 you are forwarding traffic to?

Comment: It is 80 - 192.168.11.100:80 because that is a web server

Comment: Try this `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.100:80` ..replace `eth0` with the actual interface.

Comment: I tried iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j
 DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.100:80

but nothing happend! :(

Comment: Did you have the `FORWARD` and `INPUT` chain rules set beforehand to allow traffic on 80 and 443 ports?

Comment: No I didn't. How to do that? Please help me. I'm newbie with this iptables and networking!

Comment: Set this two rules beforehand: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`, `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` ....Do the same for port 443..

Comment: Still nothing happened. I test on my mobile and my computer :(

Comment: Please add the output of `iptables -nvL`

Comment: Here is it:

http://pastebin.com/Zj4PtrT5

Comment: You have two interfaces `eth0` and `br0`..did you put the correct interface name?

Comment: I has use both eth0, eth1, ath1, ath0

Why my command just can't affect with LAN IP? With server ip, like google.com's ip. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -i eth0 -d 192.168.11.100  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.100
```

You have to change interface `eth0`

Comment: I changed interface eth0 to my wireless interface ath0, but nothing happened!

"-d 192.168.11.100" what is this mean?

Comment: `-d` agains of `-s` : `-d` means desination address, `-s` : source address.

Comment: A good solution , eliminate `-i YOUR_WIRELESS`

Comment: I used -i ath0 but nothing happened!

Comment: I say eliminate, eliminate means remove.

Comment: Hmm, still nothing happened when i removed -i parameter

Answer (score 1):

Okay! My problem has been solve.

I used this command (like i posted above)

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.100
```

I don't know that is working because i tested on computer has ip address 192.168.11.100.

When i use mobile to connect to my network, it works!

So thank you guys so much for helping me!